# AngularJS slider customized Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a slider but i want values in the different range. [image: This is how the slider looks.]
But instead of 1-10 values, I want values to be 1 Lakh, 2 Lakhs, 3 Lakhs, 5 Lakhs, 10 Lakhs and more than 10 Lakhs. How do i set the value set which also prints the text. I have combined rg-slider with my code.

```
<rg-slider
    tracker-class="my-tracker rg-tracker-with-animation"
    navigator-class="my-navigator"
    bound-var="sliderValue"
    show-navigator="true"
    navigator-from="1"
    navigator-to="16">
</rg-slider>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like it was built into the `rg-slider` directive that you're using. Instead of complicating things, I would suggest that you use a more versatile one, like this:

http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/index.html

**Update:**

Copy the following code into this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L/) and click run:

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {

   //Slider with ticks and values
    $scope.slider_ticks_values = {
        value: 0,
        options: {
            ceil: 5,
            floor: 0,
            showTicksValues: true,
            translate: function (value) {
                return value + ' Lakhs';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
        <header>
             <h1>AngularJS Touch Slider</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
             <h2>Slider with ticks and values</h2>

            <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider_ticks_values.value" rz-slider-options="slider_ticks_values.options"></rzslider>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. but i want to print text along with my value. i am not getting how to do that

Comment: Thanks. Related this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803661/how-to-set-time-in-rang-slider-in-angular-js