# How to set time in rang slider in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rangeslider

I am using Slider with draggable range(https://jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L/) in angular js for the time selection. I want to set time in this slider. So my clock is from 00.00 to 24.00. But I want to set time with 10 minutes interval, Like `00.10, 00.20, 00.30, 00.40, 00.50, 01.00, 01.10,01.10`

```html
<article>
  <h2>Slider with draggable range</h2>

  <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider_draggable_range.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider_draggable_range.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider_draggable_range.options"></rzslider>
</article>
```

---

```js
// Slider with draggable range
$scope.slider_draggable_range = {
  minValue: 1,
  maxValue: 8,
  options: {
    ceil: 10,
    floor: 0,
    draggableRange: true
  }
};
```

---

```js
$scope.slider_draggable_range = {
  minValue: $scope.fromTime,
  maxValue: $scope.toTime,
  options: {
    ceil: 24,
    floor: 0,
    draggableRange: true,
    showTicks: true,
    hideLimitLabels: true,
    hourBase: function(value) {
      return (((value > 1 && value < 12) || value > 25) ? '0' : '') + (value + 22) % 24 + '00 hrs'
    },
    steps: pules()
  }
};
```

I can't post my full code. Because it is not possible. I am selecting time by hour basis like 10.00,11.00,12.00......But right now I want to time from like 1.10, 1.20,1.30.
[image]

When I used statically   `minValue: 4.40` then it will point 4 and when I set `4.60` then it will point to `5`, So its convert into round figure value. Not in Points.

```js
$scope.slider_draggable_range = {
  minValue: 4.40,
  maxValue: 7,
  options: {
    ceil: 24,
    floor: 0,
    draggableRange: true
  }
};
```

> ceil:24 limit,
>    floor: starting point,
>       minvalue:plote starting point for
>   rang,
>       maxvalue:plote ending point for rang

Please share your idea. This question is very important for me and your answer valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, The thing you want, can achieved using the [`stepsArray`](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/blob/master/src/rzslider.js#L50) option.

The idea is to use the option to set the options by yourself. Thats way you can set it to non integer numbers.

(Search for the demo `Slider with Alphabet` in http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/)

Like this (Not the case, just an example):

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  var arr = getRange().map(n => {
    return {
      value: n,
      legend: n
    };
  });
  
  $scope.slider = {
    minValue: '10.50',
    maxValue: '14.20',
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      stepsArray: arr
    }
  };
});

function getRange() {
  var arr = [];
  var d = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < (6 * 24); i++) {
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 10);
    arr.push(leadZero(d.getHours()) + '.' + leadZero(d.getMinutes()));
  }
  return arr;
}

function leadZero(time) {
  return time < 10 ? '0' + time : time;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #1f2636;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

header {
  background: #0db9f0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: -40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
}

article {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.field-title {
  width: 100px;
}

.vertical-sliders {
  margin: 0;
}

.vertical-sliders>div {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>AngularJS Touch Slider</h1>

    </header>
    <article>
      <h2>Simple slider</h2>
      Model:
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.minValue" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.maxValue" />
      <br/>
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct, But  want to set interval of 10 minutes, Like start 00.00, 00.10, 00.20, 00.30, 00.40, 00.50, 1.00, 1.10,1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 1.50, 2.00 and so on. and my click is 00.00 to 24.00(23.50 to 00.00).

Comment: My clock is 00.00 to 24.00(00.00,00.10...........12.00,12.10...........13.00.......23.50 and 00.00)

Comment: I thought that you can take it from here (it was just an example) :) But anyway, I did it for you. Take a look.

Comment: Can we add -4 and +4. And make 32Hrs slider. Like 8:10,8:20.8:30....12:00..........24:00,00:10,00:20,3:50,4:00. Mean Start from 8 0'clock and and 4 o'clock. It covers three days. First day night 4 hrs and third day covers4 hrs morinig 4 o'clock

Comment: Could you see this link. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350964/make-32-hrs-range-in-rzslider-in-angular-js

Comment: I don't want to trouble you but I think I am little bit weak some maths thats why I ask for the help. I am improving my math and logical...your help is appreciated :)